# SendMail .forward file doesn't deliver messages to subfolders

Tags: debian, email, exim

I'm using SendMail and Exim4 on a Debian box to deliver mail, been running for a while without hiccups. I've been experimenting with using a .forward file to deliver e-mail to subfolders of my inbox, but I've not been able to get things to work satisfactorily.

My .foward file looks like this:

```
# Exim filter
if error_message then finish endif

if $h_X-Spam-Status: CONTAINS "Yes"
     or
  $h_X-Spam-Flag: CONTAINS "Yes"
then
  save $home/Maildir/.Junk/
  finish
endif
```

And I have a few rules that will use $h_subject or $h_from to filter email. I test that the rules work with the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bf .forward < some_email_that_matches
```

And I see from the output that it will deliver it to the subfolder that I define, which exists. I've set the permissions of the .forward file to 644.

However, whenever I try to actually send e-mail that hits any of these rules, it never gets delivered, and seems to get stuck in the mail system somewhere. I'm not sure where to look for more information or a error messages on my system for this, I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was asking a question impossible for you all to answer :)

The other rules that were not working used to look like this:

```
if $h_from: contains "Ebay"
then
  save $home/Maildir/.ebay
  finish
endif
```

But as it points out on [this blog](http://blog.edseek.com/~jasonb/articles/exim4_courier/exim4.html), I need to add a trailing slash, like this:

```
if $h_from: contains "Ebay"
then
  save $home/Maildir/.ebay/
  finish
endif
```

Otherwise it doesn't work. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

To see what's happening with messages that have been sent normally, look in /var/log/maillog (or wherever your syslog config puts the mail logs). There should be a set of lines in there for each message the system has handled.
If test messages aren't being bounced and aren't appearing either in your inbox of the folder you've specified in the filter file there should be something in maillog to say why. Once you've got that information, update the question.

Comment: Thanks Paul, my log files were in /var/log/mail.log, but I didn't see any useful output in there.